# How to find not selected items in Many to Many Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following Database structure.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :member_categories
  has_many :members, :through => :member_categories
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :member_categories
  has_many :categories, :through => :member_categories
end

class MemberCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "member_categories"
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :category
end
```

I can get any member categories as the following statement

```
Member.first.categories
```

there i find categories assigned to the member. I need to select the categories those are not assigned to the member. How can i write a scope to accomplish this.

Please advise, thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a suitable job for a scope. Just write a method to find all categories with IDs not in the set of category IDs associated with the given member:

```
class Member
  has_many :member_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :member_categories

  def not_categories
    Category.where('id not in (?)', categories.pluck(:id))
  end
end
```

Comment: This solution is working fine. Thanks But there are two queries are running in console can we avoid it? first one to select the member categories and 2nd one to select categories with not in condition

Comment: Maybe via `Category.where('id not in (?)', categories.to_sql)`, but why bother? This is easy, and clear, and works well. You could build the query up to be a nested `select ... where id not in (select...)` but I wouldn't bother with the extra effort unless this actually proves to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Just to avoid a db interaction. Any ways thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: @meager I just edited the answer. As there was noting when `categories.pluck(:id)` returns NULL

Comment: Pluck will always return an array of 0 or more items. It will never be `nil?`.

Comment: its returning null i fixed this by replacing nil? with empty? and its working fine now.